# Check which object call to event method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have ComboBoxs, each one have its SelectedIndexChanged event.
I don't want to write each ComboBox's event but I want to write one event method that check which ComboBox call to an event and let control do specific method for each Combobox.
I've searched and wrote like this:

```
private void eventmethod(object sender, EventArgs s)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb != null & cb.Name.Equals("combobox1"))
    {
        method1();
    }
    else if (cb != null & cb.Name.Equals("combobox2"))
    {
        method2();
    }
}
```

Is there more efficient way to check?

Comment: Maybe `if (sender == combobox1)`?

Comment: you can `return` immediately if `cb`  is _null_

Comment: If it is THAT different what happens between comboboxes you really should have separate event handlers.

Comment: Why are you assigning a single handler to both controls if the two controls need to do entirely different things?

Comment: @Servy I think it easy for me to view each combobox do in one event handler.

Comment: @user3578245 Then just look at the block of code that is assigning the event handler for each combobox.  Refactor it out into its own method if you want, so that you can see it all in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach breaks the [**Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) unless every [**ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) does the same.

It is always best to have an event handler for each control so that specific behaviour can be easily separated. If a specific behaviour is given for each [**ComboBox**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx), and they also have a common behaviour, then use a helper method to perform common tasks.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    doesCommonTasksToBePerformedThroughAHelperMethod();
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Does specific tasks
    doesCommonTasksToBePerformedThroughAHelperMethod();
}

private void doesCommonTasksToBePerformedThroughAHelperMethod() {
    // Perform common tasks
}
```

This is the prefered practice.

Otherwise, check for the control itself.

```
var cb = sender as ComboBox;

if (cb == null) return;

switch(cb) {
    case cb.Equals(comboBox1): 
        // Do something
        break;
    case cb.Equals(comboBox2):
        // Do something
        break;
}
```

**switch** statements are rarely a good thing. Here are some links on the topic.

1. [**How to explain why a developer should avoid case statements and create some new classes?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090124/162167)
2. [**Refactoring a Switch statement**](http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/10/refactoring-a-switch-statement/)
3. [**Switch Statements**](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/switch-statements)

Comment: I completely agree that I break the SRP and To write separate event handler is more efficient way. :D

Answer (score 1):

It is much better practice to have individual event handlers for each control and then have them call the same method if they do the same thing:

```
void combo1_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod();
}
void combo2_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CommonMethod();
}
```

In your case, they do not do the same thing, so it makes even more sense to have separate handlers:

```
void combo1_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Method1();
}
void combo2_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Method2();
}
```

An exception to this rule would be if you were creating controls on the fly, but even then you're probably going to be using delegates.

Comment: It makes *no sense* to have separate event handlers for controls that should all do the same thing when the same event is fired.  It of course does make sense to have separate handlers when the controls should do entirely different things.

Comment: @Servy: I disagree. More often than not I have run into cases long after code has been released where a specific control's event had to change. I guess I could add a new event at that time, but it was so much easier to find that control's event and modify it w/o worry that I was clobbering something else.

Comment: If you need to call a different method when an event is fired for a control then attach a different method as the handler for that event.  That is *no* harder, nor does it have any more significant effects to unrelated code, than creating an additional wrapper method.  This is simply filling up the code with fluff that makes finding the *meaningful* content harder.

Comment: +1 It is always best to have separate methods and call a helper method that will perform common tasks as it makes it glaringly obvious that it does nothing else.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller What *possible* value does it add?  How is assigning the same method as the handler to several controls any less glaringly obvious that the event of those controls all calls the same method?  This makes it *less* obvious.  When you have code that is specifically attaching different handlers to each control it is *specifically* sending a message to the reader of the code that the controls do different things for that event.  It makes it *more confusing* to the reader.

Comment: Because you have to go in designer to observe that each control actually does the same. As a back-end developer, it is more obvious to see the name of the control in the event handler method and see that it is actually calling a method. So, if you know what ComboBox you want to handle, you know what it does, and if you have to add a behaviour, there is no need to create the handler apart, as it already exists. Plus, as stated in my answer, it breaks the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement:

```
private void eventmethod(object sender, EventArgs s)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb == null) return;
    switch (cb.Name)
    {
        case "combobox1":
            method1();
            break;
        case "combobox2":
            method2();
            break;
    }
}
```

This isn't necessarily the best way of doing this, but it does remove the need for multiple null checks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to check for null multiple times, just do it once and return if found.  also no need to check the name as you can just check for the control ie combobox.  Being that you are calling a different method there is no harm in having multiple controls pointing to this event. I would also surround it with a try catch statement.

```
private void eventmethod(object sender, EventArgs s)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    //check for null once and return if found
    if(cb == null) return;
    //no need to call for the name just check for the combobox
    //assuming the name of the control is combobox1 and combobox2
    if (cb.Equals(combobox1))
    {
        method1();
    }
    else if (cb.Equals(combobox2))
    {
        method2();
    }
}
```